# Nested query for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Campaign 
`has_many:ads`

Ad

```
belongs_to: campaign
has_many :likes
```

Like

```
belongs_to :ad
```

I want to count the likes of all ads in campaign.How I query it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add relation to Campaign

```
has_many :likes, through: :ads
```

after that you can use: campaign.likes.count